# first time user to Ruby on Rails program

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm new user here. and this is my first question regarding Ruby on Rails. so, i wanted to ask what is the correct program version of Ruby on Rails, i have seen only 2.1 and 2.2.

i was looking for 5.0 to install and use it for first time. i chose RoR (nickname for Ruby on Rails) to create a website that can have many useful features like a site would do. but i'm at loss because i have no idea where i could find a RoR 5.0 or should i just install a older package of RoR to update to 5.0?

also, i have additional questions.

1: is RoR a program that can help you make website or blog, forum? or it's just a one in all package?

2: can you actually put together a section inside a site for news information/updates?

3: where do you find or make a code for mailing list which users can have a mail updates sent to their email?

these are my questions, you see i'm quite fond of a site that is run on RoR. so i'd like to try my hand on creating a site of my own, particularly one with a forum. like any kind of development, it's fun to learn. will you answer my questions and help me learn the program of Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is a programming language which has it's own version number. Rails is a library written in Ruby which has it's own version number as well.

The version of Ruby is not the same as the version of Rails. [Rails 5.x](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) requires Ruby version 2.2.2 or higher.

You can view the versions of each by using

```
$ ruby --version
$ rails --version
```

You can use the latest stable version of Ruby. – get it from here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ (The current latest stable is **2.3.1**)

To get the latest version of Rails, use the `gem install` command. (The current latest stable version is **5.0.0.1**)

```
$ gem install rails
```